# How to get Facebook post id?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making an iPhone app in which Facebook post sharing option is available. Now I want to show all the likes and comments of that post. I know that we can do it through http://graph.facebook.com/post_id/comments . Now can you tell me how to get the `post_id` of my post or shared link?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you post anything on facebook. In your

`- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result`

method you will get the result.. Just print that result. You will get the post_id if you are using FB SSO

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your app posts to the me/feed endpoint, using the Facebook SDK 3.1 you can set up a completion handler to grab the post id:

```
[FBRequestConnection
 startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
 parameters:self.postParams
 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                     id result,
                     NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         // Handle error
     } else {
         NSString *postId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
     }
 }];
```

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/ for an example of how to post.